# c++/g++ comparing a WORD to a CHAR for magic numbers

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

I am using G++ but would also like to support CLANG/OSX for the following:

I load a picture from a file, and parse it into a vector of char's type defined as `byte`. This works, and I can save it, send it over sockets, and so on.

My (on purpose minimal) class `picture` is essentially wrapping around those bytes.

```
class picture
{
public:
    typedef char byte;

    picture(std::string filename)
    {
        std::ifstream bytestream(filename, 
                                 std::ios::in | std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
        if (bytestream.is_open())
        {
            bytestream.seekg(0, std::ios_base::end);
            std::streampos fileSize = bytestream.tellg();
            bytearray_.resize(fileSize);
            bytestream.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);
            bytestream.read(&bytearray_[0], fileSize);
        }
    }

private:
    std::vector<byte> bytearray_;
}
```

However, I need to be able to determine if this is a PNG, JPG or other type of file.
The [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Magic_numbers_in_files) come to rescue: I simply want to find if the first two bytes, contain a sequence of words `89 50` or `FF D8` - everything else I will disregard.

By using printf I verified through the use of some pictures:

```
printf("%x", bytearray_[0] & 0xff);
printf("%x", bytearray_[1] & 0xff);
```

I got: `8950` for `lenna.png` and `ffd8` for `cat.jpg`.

I understand that I am looking for a WORD (2 bits) inside two CHAR (bytes),
and that the easiest way to confirm it would be via a XOR:

```
bool png = (&bytearray_[0] ^ '89') && (&bytearray_[1] ^ '50');
bool jpg = (&bytearray_[0] ^ 'ff') && (&bytearray_[1] ^ 'd8');
```

The above of course doesn't work, I am comparing CHAR to `int`, whereas I need to extract the WORD.
I also understand that this might be compiler/platform specific, I have no problem restricting the code to GCC/Linux and/or CLANG/OSX.

- How can I do such a comparison in C++?
- Should I cast the CHAR to a WORD, or cast the WORD literal to a CHAR?

Comment: What's wrong with simply `bytearray_[0] == 0x89 &&bytearray_[1] == 0x50`? You make it way too complicated.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: The _answer section_ is down there, bro: ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓

Comment: I just had no clue how to do it in C++

Comment: Where did you get the idea to do an XOR? Why did you write `&bytearray_[0]`? Why did you try to create multi-character literals like `'89'`? Why did you apply `& 0xff` to single `char`s (which can't be greater than that anyway)? Since when is a "WORD" comprised of two bits? Lots of mysteries here. Try to make fewer random assumptions in the future.

Comment: I remember from assembly that a XOR will either equal true or false. Didn't know that `0x` defines the primitive.

Comment: @Ælex: There are many, many operations that will result in either true or false; you can't just pick the first one that pops into your mind and pretend that means it'll do what you want. I suggest picking up an introductory book on C++ so that you can learn the language before proceeding with your project.

Comment: Thanks for the help @LightnessRacesinOrbit :-)

Comment: No problem - good luck!

Comment: @Ælex *"XOR will either equal true or false"* only for an individual bit, because it is a bitwise operation. And `0x` is a prefix to a numerical value that defines it to be hexadecimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any of this complexity, nor any casts.

Just simple comparisons of the individual byte values will do:

```
const bool is_png = (bytearray_[0] == 0x89 && bytearray_[1] == 0x50);
const bool is_jpg = (bytearray_[0] == 0xFF && bytearray_[1] == 0xD8);
```